# Detecting overlapped dates and updating the newest record SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, common-table-expression

I want to be able to detect all records (some duplicated) and marking the ones who are overlapped (the records uploaded after) with others as `OVER`. For that I have the SELECT to return existing overlapped records and the CTE to set this column to `OVER`.

My problem is adapting the select query to mark the newest with this value and store it inside the cte as I'm unfamilliar with SQL.

The select:

```
select t.* 
    from testtable t where exists 
    (select 1 from testtable t2 
    where t.idd = t2.idd
            AND t.id<>t2.id
            AND t2.beg <= t.end
            AND t.beg <= t2.end)
```

The half way done CTE:

```
;with cte
        as (select t.*, Row_number() over (partition by idd order by date_uploaded desc) RN 
            from testtable as t)
    update cte set overlapped = 'OVER'
    where RN > 1
    and (overlapped is null or overlapped <> 'UNIQUE')
```

Example data, how it should look like:

```
overlapped ID   idd    iduser iddate name beg end date_uploaded
UNIQUE  52  -1907372231 666 201802  sol 2018-09-01  2018-09-10  2018-09-12 
OVER    53  -1907372231 666 201802  sol 2018-09-10  2018-09-12  2018-09-13
```

Notice how the row 53 overlaps BEG date with END

Any help with my problem it's hugely appreciated.

Comment: Surely there's a good duplicate out there, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff @TabAlleman Desired result uploaded, sampled data it's the same but with `over_stat` set with the string `unique` as default.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating the CTE, use a CASE expression when you SELECT from it:

```
;with cte
        as (select t.*, Row_number() over (partition by idd order by date_uploaded desc) RN 
            from testtable as t)
    SELECT CASE 
      WHEN RN > 1 and (overlapped is null or overlapped <> 'UNIQUE') THEN 'OVER'
      ELSE overlapped
    END AS overlapped
FROM cte
```

Comment: The code keeps OVERLAPPED as 'OVER', why use the case instead of the update? Btw: I added de desired result into the main question. Thanks. Edit: My bad, the code runs and display newest record as OVER, tho I need to check if its actually overlapped.